# few doubts on following on Excel serial to date conversion code

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, date

I have a few doubts about following the code. can anyone please help me to understand the below code?

```
                        async function getNewDate(xlSerial) {
                            // milliseconds since 1899-31-12T00:00:00Z, corresponds to xl serial 0.
                            let xlSerialOffset = -2209075200000; 
                            let elapsedDays;
                            // each serial up to 60 corresponds to a valid calendar date.
                            // serial 60 is 1900-02-29. This date does not exist on the calendar.
                            // we choose to interpret serial 60 (as well as 61) both as 1900-03-01
                            // so, if the serial is 61 or over, we have to subtract 1.
                            if (xlSerial < 61) {
                                elapsedDays = xlSerial;
                            }
                            else {
                                elapsedDays = xlSerial - 1;
                            }
                            // javascript dates ignore leap seconds
                            // each day corresponds to a fixed number of milliseconds:
                            // 24 hrs * 60 mins * 60 s * 1000 ms
                            let millisPerDay = 86400000;

                            let jsTimestamp = xlSerialOffset + elapsedDays * millisPerDay;
                            return new Date(jsTimestamp);
                        }
```

1. Here in the code can anyone tell me what is **let xlSerialOffset = -2209075200000;**
   2)why do subtract  1 in second condition conditions?

Comment: It literally says on the comment above the line - // milliseconds since 1899-31-12T00:00:00Z, corresponds to xl serial 0.

Comment: xl serial 0 means 1900/01/01 which is one day difference from 1899/12/31, can you please help me to understand this

Comment: Because of the other explanation about 29.2.1900. seems clear enough.

Comment: i got to know that 2209075200000 is 25568 days to milliseconds but I am not getting why - is used(negative value)..can you please help me to understand

Comment: Just clarified in detail @wiilan in my answer